# Generate multiple outputs with Hadoop Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've got this file containing a list of data in Hadoop. I've build a simple Pig script which analyze the file by the **id number**, and so on...

The last step I'm looking for is this: I'd like to to create (store) a file for each unique **id number**. So this should depend on a group step...however, I haven't understood if this is possible (maybe there is a custom store module?).

Any idea?

Thanks

Daniele

Answer (score 2):

While keeping in mind what is said by frail, [MultiStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html), in PiggyBank, seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

for getting an output(file or anything) you need to assign data to a variable, thats how it works with `STORE`. If id's are limited and finite you can `FILTER` them one by one and then `STORE` them. (I always do that for action types which is about 20-25).

But if you need to get each unique id file badly then make 2 files. 1 with whole data in it grouped by id, 1 with just unique ids. Then try generating 1(or more if you have too many) pig scripts that FILTER BY that id. But it's a bad solution. Assuming you would group 10 ids in a pig script you would have (unique id count/10) pig scripts to run.

Beware that Hdfs ain't good at handling too many small files.

**Edit:**
A better solution would be to GROUP and SORT by unique id to a big file. Then since its sorted you can easily divide the contents with a 3rd party script.